# Identify a specific incuded project class when they're multiple classes of same name

Tags: java, spring

I have (2+) projects included into my `genxml` projet e.g. `framework1` and `framework2`. They are slighly different versions of the same framework and they both have the class `AbstractScreenTest.class`. Each `AbstractScreenTest.class` has a different annotation

```
@MyAnnotation(name="version",  value = "71automation")
@MyAnnotation(name="version",  value = "72automation")
```

Is there anyway using the annotation or other ways I can specifiy which AbstractScreenTest.class I want to use in the code below as at the
moment only the first instance found is used.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(true);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(AbstractScreenTest.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> components = provider.findCandidateComponents(candiatePackage);
```

Comment: Are both of your classes in the same package?  If so, I would think you won't have a choice of which file you get (besides ordering the classpath a specific way).

Comment: Yea they are both in the same package.

Comment: Have you noticed at runtime that only one of them is available?  Two classes with the same package and name are surely going to give you grief at runtime.  You could probably achieve what you are after by doing some sort of build time annotation processing, but that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: You're in quite a pickle. Why do you need both versions of the framework?

Comment: Different people will be working on different versions of the framework which will eventually merge together so I need to support all versions of the frameworks being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the Spring problem, JVM cannot have two versions of a class loaded simultaneously in one classloader.

The only way to load different version of the same class is to use two different classloaders with different classpaths. There is no easy solution, especially if these frameworks use other classes which could interact.